# Apparition effect without the beamer package

Tags: beamer

I want to implement a presentation template in LaTeX that look very like the one [here](https://github.com/thib1235/LaTeX/blob/master/Presentation/LibreOfficeModel_TM_YvesZumbach_2014-2015_Soutenance.pdf).

Until here, I did just fine using the article class with geometry, tikz and some custom commands. However a problem arose: *the article class does not implement apparition effects!*

Beamer allows to do such things (with commands like \pause, \only, etc.) but the code that manage it (beamerbaseoverlay.sty if I am not mistaken) doesn't look like being included in something other than beamer-class documents...

Does anyone know a package that would add apparition effects to LaTeX document. Or a way to add beamer's code to mine?

Comment: What is the apparition effect? Which page is the problematic one ?

Comment: The apparition effect is not visible in the pdf file. I uploaded the .odp file so that they are visible.

Comment: Any particular reason, why you do not use beamer?

Comment: where is this file and can you explain what this effect is? I never heard it

Comment: The template I want to define is really different from the default beamer template. It would be more work to modify beamer's template than to simply redefine a new one based on the article class. The file is in [the same repo](https://github.com/thib1235/LaTeX/tree/master/Presentation) (with .odp extension). An *apparition effect* is just some text appearing on a slide after pressing Enter or the right arrow on the keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried the `texpower` package?

Comment: @Thérèse Many thanks Thérèse, the package you mentioned looks exactly like want I was looking for! Moreover the texpower package gives on its homepage alternative packages that provide the same functionnalities (ppower4 and prosper). I will read their documentation and choose the one that will hopefully fulfil my needs. Would you write an answer so that I can vote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `texpower` package allows for pauses and transitions of many sorts, without `beamer`. So you can use, for example, the article class, and set the page size and margins to anything you like with `geometry`, and produce documents that look nothing like `beamer`, and perhaps like nothing on earth.  Here’s a silly example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,fontspec,microtype}
\usepackage[display]{texpower}
\setmainfont{Antique Olive FS}[
  Color=DarkGreen]
\linespread{1.103}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[centering,papersize={288pt,384pt},hmargin=1.5em,tmargin=55ex,bmargin=1.5em]{geometry}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
\put(0,0){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{nip}}}}}
% image and sentiment from https://twitter.com/HenriLeChatNoir
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\Large\bfseries
If you gaze long into the catnip,\pause
the catnip also gazes into you.\pause
\begin{flushright}
  –Henri, le Chat Noir
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image: first slide]
[image: second slide]
[image: third slide]

But `texpower` is capable of much more than this; compile `fancyexample.tex` from the documentation for something very impressive.